# curve-fit interprets the input of a function both as array and scalar

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am currently stuck on the following problem:
I want to perform the following fit using curve_fit:

```
def fit_fun(x,c,gamma,B):
    return (c/3.)*np.log((60./pi)*np.sin(pi 
  *x/60.)+ gamma+B*v[x]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_fun,range(1,60),entropy)
```

where v and entropy are given lists and I want c, gamma, B to be float scalars.

The error message I get is the following:

"only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

From what I understood, the problem is due to the fact that the implementation of curve_fit is such that at a certain point it treats the input as an array, which cannot be used as an index in the last term of the definition of the function. 
I do not know how to get out of this apparent contradiction for which  x is integer at first and then it gets into an array in the fitting procedure.

Comment: try to share also the content of your lists and the variables contents that you are using to make your example reproducible

Comment: The lists v,entropy can be any lists of length 59 of floats,I extract them from an input file, but any list of this type should work to check whether it is fitting the data. Pi is just 3.14...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your x value in curve_fit is passed as -list- and therefore you cannot use it as index for your v array.

I made an example with mocked variables. If you try to print the value sent to your function (x) is a list. I also casted the X value to int. Anyway I changed the indexing for v. I don't know if in this way the curve is correctly fitted

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
from numpy import pi

entropy = [0.1 for i in range(60)]
v = [i for i in range(60)]

def fit_fun(x, c, gamma, B):
    return (c/3.) * np.log(60./pi)  * np.sin(pi * x/60.) + gamma + np.array(B) * [v[int(i)] for i in x]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_fun, np.array([i for i in range(0,60)]), entropy)
```

Comment: Could I ask you if your example would solve the issue? As far as I know, .astype converts the array elements into integers but x is still an array.

Comment: @Igotta my answer is explaining why you can't use curve_fit for your specific case

Comment: @Igotta I changed my answer adding the handling for the indexing.